# identifying sudden change in value given a list of values over time

Tags: probability, statistics, finance

I have a list of the average price of an item in a game over time. Things don't tend to move much. I am wondering how I can detect whether a new value inserted is a surprising movement in price.

I assume the finance area has a lot of models for this kind of stuff. I'm looking for something simple and possibly already in a mathematics library for any given language

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a best answer to this question until you define exactly what you want first. But one simple method to do this is to work out the mean and variance of all (or only more recent ones, or perhaps even a Recursive Least Squares estimate) past values. This can be done with a simple algorithm, e.g. for the mean

$\langle x \rangle_i = \frac{n-1}{n}\langle x \rangle_{i-1} + \frac 1 n x_i$

Say your code has the estimate of the mean as `mean` and the estimate of the variance as `variance`, then one way to measure the 'surprise' could be:

```
surprise = abs(newValue - mean)/sqrt(variance)
```

Unfortunately, this is not an unbiased estimator. If you want it to be unbiased, you should replace `sqrt(variance)` with the mean deviation of your values. For the estimator to be unbiased, we need $E[surprise]=1$.

A more advanced method would involve some machine learning techniques. You could form a statistical model of the values you are obtaining by modelling the values as a Gaussian process (for example). Then this would allow you to calculate the probability of the next data point being a certain value. The lower the probability of the value you actually get, the more surprising it is

Comment: I'm working with an API that gives the current average. Can't get the variance of these averages as a result. I did consider assuming the data is normal and applying a CDF threshhold to determine whether it was an improbable price. I think this is what you're saying in your last paragraph? We've reached the peak of my limited knowledge of statistics, sorry if I'm confused.

Comment: You can calculate an estimate of the variance yourself if you have the full list of values, it's a simple formula

Comment: That was the general idea I was getting at - you can form a statistical model (which can be anything of your choosing, or can be based off the data) which models the data you are receiving. If this is an accurate model, then the probability of the new data point is a good estimate of the 'surprise'. The method you describe is a good starting point, IF your data is well modelled by a Gaussian.

Comment: And Gaussian processes, which I mentioned, are actually a much more general method of performing regression on random processes, they actually consists of an infinite dimensional multivariate Gaussian. But if your statistics knowledge is limited, I wouldn't bother with them.